# tilelist scrollbar disappears when movie is resized

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have an image viewer movie and in HTML it's size is defined in percents width=80% and height=80%. There is a vertical TileList in the movie and more thumbnails than fits in the movie. So there is normally a scrollBar besides the Tilelist. When I resize the browser window the movie is resized ok but the scrollBar disappears! Here is some code from the movie:

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    .
    .
    .
    function resizeHandler(e:Event):void {
        movieBackground.height = stage.stageHeight;
        movieBackground.width = stage.stageWidth;
        movieBackground.x = 0;
        movieBackground.y = 0;
        thumbs.columnWidth = stage.stageWidth / 6; 
        thumbs.rowHeight = stage.stageHeight / 6; 
        thumbs.columnCount = 1;
        thumbs.rowCount = (stage.stageHeight) / thumbs.rowHeight; 
        thumbClip.x = stage.stageWidth - thumbs.columnWidth;
        thumbClip.y = 0;
        resizeCurrentImage();
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in this code shows what's happening to the scrollBar - what are you using for that?

Comment: I have tried: thumbs.scrollPolicy = "auto" and "on" neither works!

Comment: try reloading all the thumbs in the list

Comment: It's not an option there must be a better solution.

Comment: I have the tilelist on the right side of the movie. Now I discovered that when you resize the movie the tilelist "jumps" about 15 pixels to the right so scrollbar gets out of the movie. All you have to do is to move tilelist to the left when resizing the movie :) 

        function resizeHandler(e:Event):void {
         .
          .
         .
         thumbClip.x = stage.stageWidth - thumbs.columnWidth - 15;
         thumbClip.y = 0;